# pythonの並列化について

Tags: python

pythonのプログラムを並列化しようと考え、pythonのモジュールであるmultiprocessingを実装した所以下のエラーが発生致しました。
使用しているモジュールは主に遺伝的アルゴリズム用のDEAPというモジュールです。
[DEAPのリファレンス](http://deap.readthedocs.org/en/master/index.html)
コメントであるように`pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)`をmainの下に置いた所プロセスは5つ生まれマルチプロセスにはなれたのですが、タスクマネージャーで見たところそのプロセスのうち1つのみ稼働している見た目だけマルチプロセスになってしまいました。
http://gazo.shitao.info/r/i/20160125185509_000.png
1つだけ25%でそれ以外0％であり、尚且つプロセスを3つ生み出す命令しているのにプロセスが4つ生み出されているため、プロセスを生み出す処理と動作する処理を別に行っていると考えられるのですがその理由がわかりません。どのようにするべきか教えてくれれば助かります。

```
import random
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Lock
#from scoop import futures

from deap import algorithms
from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools

toolbox = base.Toolbox()

def main():
#     random.seed(64)
    NGEN = 5
    MU = 75
    LAMBDA = 75
    CXPB = 0.6
    MUTPB = 0.3

    pop = toolbox.population(n=MU)
    hof = tools.ParetoFront()
    stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats.register("avg", numpy.mean, axis=0)
    stats.register("std", numpy.std, axis=0)
    stats.register("min", numpy.min, axis=0)
    stats.register("max", numpy.max, axis=0)

    algorithms.eaMuPlusLambda(pop, toolbox, MU, LAMBDA, CXPB, MUTPB, NGEN, stats,
                              halloffame=hof)
    return pop, stats, hof
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
    toolbox.register('map', pool.map_async)
    for var in range(0,5):
　　　　　・・・・・
```

**追記**
並列化に関してですが、このページを参考にしております。[DEAPの並列化](http://deap.readthedocs.org/en/master/tutorials/basic/part4.html?highlight=multiprocessing)
ここにあるようにMultiprocessing Moduleを用いて並列化しており、中身としては以下のアルゴリズム中にあるmap関数で`multiprocessing.Pool.map_async`を呼び出すことで並列化計算していると考えています。
どこを並列化したいのかという点ですが、コメントにあるようにアルゴリズム中でmap関数が使われている点が個体の評価という点ですのでそこを並列化したいと考えています。
並列化していないバージョンですが、`if __name__ == '__main__':`以下の

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
toolbox.register('map', pool.map_async)
```

をコメントアウトするなどで動作させない場合プロセスが生まれず通常通りに動きました。
また、[参考にしたコード](http://pastebin.com/0WazVPKy)を実装した場合しっかりマルチプロセスで動いておりPCの問題ではないと思いますが、自分のコードではどこが原因となって見た目マルチプロセスになっているのかわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。
**追記2**
自分のコードですがこのような形になります。
[全コード](http://pastebin.com/4wFneYgX)
[参考にしたコード]同様にDEAPモジュールのalgorithmsを以下のように変更しております。
**変更点**
def eaMuPlusLambdaの

```
fitnesses = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
```

を

```
jobs = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
fitnesses=jobs.get()
```

としています。全文を以下に載せます。

**algorithms**

```
def eaMuPlusLambda(population, toolbox, mu, lambda_, cxpb, mutpb, ngen,
                   stats=None, halloffame=None, verbose=__debug__):
    logbook = tools.Logbook()
    logbook.header = ['gen', 'nevals'] + (stats.fields if stats else [])

    # Evaluate the individuals with an invalid fitness
    invalid_ind = [ind for ind in population if not ind.fitness.valid]
    jobs= toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
    fitnesses=jobs.get()
    for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
        ind.fitness.values = fit

    if halloffame is not None:
        halloffame.update(population)

    record = stats.compile(population) if stats is not None else {}
    logbook.record(gen=0, nevals=len(invalid_ind), **record)
    if verbose:
        print logbook.stream

    # Begin the generational process
    for gen in range(1, ngen+1):
        # Vary the population
        offspring = varOr(population, toolbox, lambda_, cxpb, mutpb)

        # Evaluate the individuals with an invalid fitness
        invalid_ind = [ind for ind in offspring if not ind.fitness.valid]
        jobs = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
        fitnesses=jobs.get()
        for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
            ind.fitness.values = fit

        # Update the hall of fame with the generated individuals
        if halloffame is not None:
            halloffame.update(offspring)

        # Select the next generation population
        population[:] = toolbox.select(population + offspring, mu)

        # Update the statistics with the new population
        record = stats.compile(population) if stats is not None else {}
        logbook.record(gen=gen, nevals=len(invalid_ind), **record)
        if verbose:
            print logbook.stream

    return population, logbook
```

**追記3**
簡単なコード

```
# coding: UTF-8
'''

'''
import multiprocessing

def nibai(x): 
    print multiprocessing.current_process()
    return x*x

def aaa():
    p = Pool(3) 
    print p.map(nibai, range(100)) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    aaa()
```

Comment: windows で python を使っていないので、想像なのですが、
`pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)` は、
`if __name__ == '__main__':` の下になければならないのではないでしょうか？マルチプロセスとは直接関係のないコードが多く、問題の切り分けが難しいです。バグを起こす最低限のコードが追記されると回答がつきやすいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。実際にやってみたところタスクマネージャーにて4つのプロセスは生まれたのですが、動いているのは1つのプロセスだけで並列に処理はしていない状況でした。マルチプロセスにする場合他になにか実装しなければいけないのでしょうか。

Comment: `toolbox.register('map', pool.map_async)`で`toolbox.map`メソッドとして登録していますが、これは後続コードで利用されていますか？同メソッドを呼ぶと、実際には`multiprocessing.Pool.map_async`が呼ばれて並列実行されるという流れのはずです。

Comment: algorithmについて追記致しました。このアルゴリズムを用いて計算をしていますが私としてはalgorithm中に`toolbox.map・・・`とあるのでここで呼び出していると考えています。

Comment: 遺伝的アルゴリズムの何を並列化しようとしているのか明らかにしてください。[別件の回答](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/19912/deap%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B%E7%B5%90%E6%9E%9C%E3%81%AE%E8%A9%B3%E7%B4%B0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)で示したように幾つかある段階のうち、並列化できるのは個体の評価くらいだと思います。それ以外はひとつ前のステップの結果に依存しますので並列化は簡単ではないと思います。実装について議論するのはその後です。そして並列化していないバージョンで動くコードを示してください。それが明らかにならない限り誰も回答できないでしょう。

Comment: @Kenji Noguchi　コメントにあうように様々変更致しました。動くコードというのがもし書いたコード全体という意味でしたら申し訳ありません、すぐに追記致します。よろしくお願いします

Comment: `for var in range(0,5)` はどんな意味があるのでしょうか？`しっかりマルチプロセスで動いて`いるコードの方では、繰り返しをしていません。プロセスが3つのはずが4つ出来ている、というのは、プロセスを起動しただけで、計算に使っていないのでは？という疑惑があります。

Comment: プロセスの数ですが、画像だとpythonのプロセスが4つなので、メインのプロセス1つ＋multiprocessingが作った3つ、で数はあっているように思えるのですが・・・（単純に画面外にもうひとつプロセスがあるだっけだったらすみません・・・

Comment: `for var in range(0.5)`はこのシミュレーションを何度も繰り返したいと考えたため書いてあります。これが悪さをしてるかと考え`for var in range(0.5)`をコメントアウトしてみましたが結果は変わらずマルチプロセスにはなりませんでした。またプロセスを起動しただけで計算に使ってないという意見には同意しますがそれが何故なのか？という点がわからず質問させていただいた次第です。

Comment: @miyako　`参考にしたコード`でも同様にmultiprocessingを実装しており`pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)・・・`としていますがこちらを実装したところメインプロセス＋multiの4つで5つというわけでなく、プロセスが4つ生まれ尚且つそれらが全部CPU=25％と計算に用いられておりました。そのためメインプロセス＋multi×3というように動くのではなくmultiに設定したもので計算しているのでは？と考えています。

Comment: eaMuPlusLambda関数自体は個体の評価を並列で実行するように正しく書かれているとおもいます。マルチプロセスになっていないと思う根拠はCPUの%だけでしょ？evaluateのなかで`print multiprocessing.current_process()`とでもすればワーカーのIDが表示されるから、IDがばらけていたら並列化できているってことです。これ以上の調査をするならコード全体を示してもらわないとむり。

Comment: 実装したところ今までの出力とは別に`<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>`,`<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>`,`<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>・・・・・`と出力されました。 ここからもやはりプロセスは生まれているとは思うのですがメインプロセス以外は動いていないかと考えているのですが、勘違いしていたら申し訳ありません。

Comment: コード全文をリンク致しました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

multiprocess版のeaMuPlusLambdaをコピペした他はimport周りを数行修正しただけですので説明は不要かと思います。ちなみに僕の環境ではmultiprocess化しないほうが速かったです。プロセス生成とプロセス間通信は一般にオーバーヘッドが大きいです。それで皆スレッドを使うわけですね。もっともPythonのスレッドはGIL(グローバル・インタープリタ・ロック）のせいでスピードが出ませんが。

```
diff -u original.py  my.py
--- original.py 2016-01-26 01:00:54.000000000 -0800
+++ my.py   2016-01-26 01:02:21.000000000 -0800
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@
 '''
 import random
 import numpy
-import matplotlib.pyplot
+#import matplotlib.pyplot
 import time
 import multiprocessing
 # from multiprocessing import Lock
@@ -42,6 +42,7 @@
 toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

 def evalKnapsack(individual):
+    print multiprocessing.current_process()
     energy = 0.0
     power = 0.0
     for item in individual:
@@ -49,7 +50,7 @@
         power += items[item][0]
     if power < MIN_POWER or energy < MIN_ENERGY:
         return 100000000000,1000000000000
-    print multiprocessing.current_process()
+
     return energy, power

 def cxSet(ind1, ind2):
@@ -77,6 +78,54 @@
 toolbox.register("mutate", mutSet)
 toolbox.register("select", tools.selSPEA2)

+def eaMuPlusLambda(population, toolbox, mu, lambda_, cxpb, mutpb, ngen,
+                   stats=None, halloffame=None, verbose=__debug__):
+    logbook = tools.Logbook()
+    logbook.header = ['gen', 'nevals'] + (stats.fields if stats else [])
+
+    # Evaluate the individuals with an invalid fitness
+    invalid_ind = [ind for ind in population if not ind.fitness.valid]
+    jobs= toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
+    print jobs
+    fitnesses=jobs.get()
+    for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
+        ind.fitness.values = fit
+
+    if halloffame is not None:
+        halloffame.update(population)
+
+    record = stats.compile(population) if stats is not None else {}
+    logbook.record(gen=0, nevals=len(invalid_ind), **record)
+    if verbose:
+        print logbook.stream
+
+    # Begin the generational process
+    for gen in range(1, ngen+1):
+        # Vary the population
+        offspring = algorithms.varOr(population, toolbox, lambda_, cxpb, mutpb)
+
+        # Evaluate the individuals with an invalid fitness
+        invalid_ind = [ind for ind in offspring if not ind.fitness.valid]
+        jobs = toolbox.map(toolbox.evaluate, invalid_ind)
+        fitnesses=jobs.get()
+        for ind, fit in zip(invalid_ind, fitnesses):
+            ind.fitness.values = fit
+
+        # Update the hall of fame with the generated individuals
+        if halloffame is not None:
+            halloffame.update(offspring)
+
+        # Select the next generation population
+        population[:] = toolbox.select(population + offspring, mu)
+
+        # Update the statistics with the new population
+        record = stats.compile(population) if stats is not None else {}
+        logbook.record(gen=gen, nevals=len(invalid_ind), **record)
+        if verbose:
+            print logbook.stream
+
+    return population, logbook
+
 def main():
     NGEN =10
     MU = 30
@@ -95,7 +144,7 @@
     stats.register("min", numpy.min, axis=0)
     stats.register("max", numpy.max, axis=0)

-    algorithms.eaMuPlusLambda(pop, toolbox, MU, LAMBDA, CXPB, MUTPB, NGEN, stats,
+    eaMuPlusLambda(pop, toolbox, MU, LAMBDA, CXPB, MUTPB, NGEN, stats,
                               halloffame=hof)

     return pop, stats, hof
```

**出力(抜粋)**

10世代目で27個体の評価が行われた部分の抜粋です。27個`<Process(PoolWorker-X, started daemon)>`とあるのでワーカーが並列に実行していることがわかります。IDの値が後の方になるにつれて入り乱れているのも並列化されている証拠。次の行にある`10 27...`とはGA/EAの10世代目で27個の個体が新たに評価されたことを示しています。先の27と一致していますね。

```
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
<Process(PoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
10  27      [  3418.33333333  34263.33333333]       [  559.66110777  3609.56907246]     [  2540.  30400.]       [  4040.  41500.]
Individual([513, 8439, 9095, 3082, 8203, 2830, 5391, 9876, 1430, 281, 9370, 7962, 7072, 5154, 9635, 8357, 5883, 2473, 4778, 2987, 4785, 5619, 4405, 1718, 9655, 8896, 6593, 9666, 5899, 4555, 8398, 2147, 468, 8014, 9815, 6104, 3988, 347, 9692, 9313, 355, 2020, 5483, 2369, 1523, 1140, 4905, 148, 6523, 4348, 1662, 4223]) (2540.0, 30400.0)
[]
[28]
[24]
[]
[deap.creator.Fitness((2540.0, 30400.0))]
elapsed_time:5.64607787132[sec]
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 5.64599 s
File: my.py
Function: x at line 152
```

**なぜCPUの利用率が上がらないのか**

並列化されている関数は次の極単純な関数です。計算コストは小さそうです。この関数を実行する時間よりも並列化のオーバーヘッド（計算の配信、結果の取得に伴うプロセス間通信など）が高ければCPUの利用率は上がりません。

```
def evalKnapsack(individual):
    print multiprocessing.current_process()
    energy = 0.0
    power = 0.0
    for item in individual:
        energy += items[item][1]
        power += items[item][0]
    if power < MIN_POWER or energy < MIN_ENERGY:
        return 100000000000,1000000000000

    return energy, power
```

**CPU利用率を見る実験**

上の関数に時間のかかる処理を入れて、CPUの利用率をみます。オーバーヘッドよりも計算コストが高ければ利用率が上がるはず。ここでは`time.sleep(5)`などとやらず、forループで無駄にCPUを消費するのがポイント。

```
def evalKnapsack(individual):
    print multiprocessing.current_process()
    print "busy loop"
    n = 0
    for i in range(100000):
        for j in range(100000):
            n += 1.1
    energy = 0.0
    power = 0.0
    for item in individual:
        energy += items[item][1]
        power += items[item][0]
    if power < MIN_POWER or energy < MIN_ENERGY:
        return 100000000000,1000000000000

    return energy, power
```

**実験結果**

Windows環境が今手元にないので、Macでtopコマンドを実行したところ、Pythonのプロセスが３つあり100%近く利用中になっていることがわかります。

[image: 並列化の様子]

**アドバイス**

もっと基礎的なプログラミングの練習をしてから、こういう大きな問題に取り組むことをお勧めしますよ。それに使い方の分からないモジュールはまず小さな問題で使って理解しましょう。例えばmultiprocessなら`def nibai(x): return x+x`みたいな簡単な関数で挙動を確かめるとか。いきなり組み合わせて結果を出そうとすると、個別に理解してから組み合わせるよりずっと時間がかかります。理解していないものを組み合わせても、どちらに動かない原因があるのかさえ分からないからね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。かいて頂いたコードを実装した所以前と変わらずメインプロセスのみ25％となりデーモンプロセスが3つ生まれましたが、この実装においてpythonのマルチプロセスではそのようにプロセス全てを使って計算することは出来ないということでしょうか。
また簡単なコードとのことで追記したコードを実装したところメインプロセスのみしか生まれなかった事から1プロセスごとのCPU性能を超えたら次のプロセスに計算を渡すといった理解でよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます、実装してみたところオーバーヘッドについて理解できていないことがわかりました。　計算コストの高い実装をしたところしっかりマルチプロセスになっていました。再度になりますがありがとうございました。